# MS Access excluding specific criteria

Tags: ms-access-2007

Im trying to filter out certain numbers in MS Access of tried "Not", "Not Like", and <> and having no luck can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show the community examples of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could use <> if you are excluding only one number, like.

```
SELECT 
    yourFieldName1,
    yourFieldName2
FROM
    yourTableName
WHERE 
    yourNumberField <> 500;
```

If you want a series of Numbers then you could use,

```
SELECT 
    yourFieldName1,
    yourFieldName2
FROM
    yourTableName
WHERE 
    (
        (yourNumberField <> 1)
        Or
        (yourNumberField <> 2)
        Or
        (yourNumberField <> 3)
        Or
        (yourNumberField <> 4)
        Or
        (yourNumberField <> 500)
    );
```

I would also use,

```
SELECT 
    yourFieldName1,
    yourFieldName2
FROM
    yourTableName
WHERE 
    yourNumberField Not In (1, 2, 3, 4, 500);
```